# While Loop Conditional statement only calls the first condition

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am experiencing unwanted behavior with my code's if statements. When I call conditional statements inside the `while loop`, only the first condition is called no matter which input is supplied. I wish for the proper input to call the properly described function and then continue back to the beginning of the loop to ask the user for another choice.

```
color_modes = ['sangria', 'ham', 'nightHawk']
print color_modes
def sangria():
    my_range = list(range(20))
    print my_range
def ham():
    print 'foo'
def nightHawk():
    print 'nightHawk'
while True:
    user_input = input('...')
    if 'sangria':
        ham()
        continue
    if 'ham':
        sangria()
        continue
    if 'nightHawk':
        nightHawk()
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Moreoever, when I use the syntax:

`if user_input == 'ham':` instead of the shorthand `if 'ham:`, the condition does not function. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2

```
user_input = input('...')
```

attempts to evaluate the user's input. If you input a string such as `ham` Python will try to evaluate the expression `ham` which will fail as shown below (unless there is a similarly named variable in scope).

```
>>> input('...')
...ham
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'ham' is not defined
```

You could fix it by using [`raw_input()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead:

```
user_input = raw_input('...')
```

and then using string comparison:

```
while True:
    user_input = raw_input('...')
    if user_input == 'ham':
        ham()
    elif user_input == 'sangria':
        sangria()
    elif user_input == 'nightHawk':
        nightHawk()
    else:
        break
```

This code also uses `elif` to avoid the unnecessary `continue` statements.

A better way is to use a dictionary to map the user input to the associated function:

```
input_map = {'ham': ham, 'sangria': sangria, 'nightHawk': nightHawk}
while True:
    func = input_map.get(raw_input('...'))
    if func is None:
        break
    func()
```

Answer (score 1):

`if 'ham'` will always pass since an not empty string is always `True`.

Instead, you must check for equality using the `==` operator.

The correct code would be:

```
color_modes = ['sangria', 'ham', 'nightHawk']
print color_modes
def sangria():
    my_range = list(range(20))
    print my_range
def ham():
    print 'foo'
def nightHawk():
    print 'nightHawk'
while True:
    user_input = input('...')
    if user_input == 'sangria':
        ham()
        continue
    if user_input == 'ham':
        sangria()
        continue
    if user_input == 'nightHawk':
        nightHawk()
        continue
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. i understand now that `raw_input` in 2.7 and `input` in python 3 return strings, but input by default in 2.7 returns an expression. I suppose it was this simple error on my part. Thank you to all for clarifiying. Thank you as well for clarifying what `if 'somestring'` does.

Answer (score 1):

`if 'sangria':` is only shorthand for `if bool('sangria'):`, which always evaluates to `if True`, therefore the first thing is ran regardless of input

You need to compare the input string. There's no shorthand / alternative way to write it like a Java switch case statement

This code looks odd, by the way.

```
if 'sangria':
    ham()
    continue
if 'ham':
    sangria()
    continue
```

If I understand what you want, you can create a function map.

```
funcs = {"ham": ham, "sangria" : sangria, "nightHawk" : nightHawk} 
user_input = input() 
funcs[user_input]() # use the string to get the function object, then call it
```